# Generating url relative to the base url in laravel 4

Tags: php, url, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel & right now building one application on L-4 but got stuck at one place. Can't able to understand how to generate url relative to base url. In laravel-3 i know this can be done by

```
$url = URL::to('user/profile');
```

But, in L-4 how we can do this.. ?

Answer (score 22):

To generate a **relative** URL, you can use `URL::route` or `URL::action` as they allow to pass a `$absolute` parameter which defaults to `true`. So to get a relative URL when using named routes for example, you can use the following:

```
URL::route('foobar', array(), false)
```

This will generate a URL like `/foobar`.

Comment: This is the closest to being a correct answer to the question. URL::route() generates a URL to a named route, and the last `false` parameter stipulates that the generated route is relative. For clarity, the generated URL will be that which the named route defined and not necessarily `/foobar`

Answer (score 6):

First you need to create a Named Route like

Say yo want to go to `http://baseurl/user` and runs the method 'showuser' define in controller 'allusers'

then your Route shold look like this:-

```
Route::get('user', array('as' => 'myuser', 'uses' => 'allusers@showuser'));
```

Now your URL to /user would be

```
$myuserurl = URL::to('/myuser');
echo $myuserurl; // would be http://baseurl/user
```

I hope this helps you. Pls refer http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes

Comment: Shouldn't that be `URL::to('myuser');` since it would be calling the route's name to figure out where to link to rather than linking directly to the route?  If it's `URL::to('/myuser')`, I believe the route should be `Route::get('/myuser', array('as' => 'myuser', 'uses' => 'allusers@showuser'));`

Comment: You can define Route without a leading slash (/) and can use directly URL:: Route  to get the named Route URL as:-  Route::get('myuser', array('as' => 'myuser', 'uses' => 'allusers@showuser')); Usage -- URL::route('myuser', array())

Comment: Downvoted as the answer is misleading. URL::to() won't route to a named route, nor will it generate a relative URL.

Comment: @sebt I understand your wish to help, but unfortunately we can't accept your edit because that code clearly conflicts with that the author said. Why not post your improved solution as your own answer instead ?

Comment: @AndréDaniel Understood. After submitting the edit in somewhat of a rush, I realised that it conflicts with SO policy on edits. Couldn't figure out how to retract it, sorry. In the end I added a comment to Holger Weis' answer which indicates the correct approach fairly clearly.