# Laravel5: Get base url or home url of the Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel-5

How can I get the base url or home url of the Laravel application ?

#### I have seen similar question. And all of them are based on laravel 4. I have tried the suggesting answer But none of these work in laravel 5. So please consider this things before vote down or treat this as a duplicate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16807843/552116

Comment: @FyodorX sorry my bad i have deleted it

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can get the base url of the Laravel application by:

```
echo url('/');
```

or

```
{{ url('/') }}
```

Read more about Laravel helpers [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#urls)

Comment: On Laravel 5.2 later, you can't use just url(). Instead, use url('/'). https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/10934